# Is there a big difference between Ubuntu with GNOME Shell and Ubuntu GNOME Remix?

Tags: unity, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I want to try Ubuntu (tried different distro's many times before), but none were really to my liking. I always seem to be drawn to Ubuntu, thanks to the PPA's and software. What I don't like is Unity, particularly the Dash. That's why I want to use GNOME Shell, I like it.

I know you can install GNOME Shell in Software Center, and uninstall Unity, but won't there be tons of Unity's configuration files left? And would upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04 still work?

I know there's GNOME Remix available, but is there any advantage over the standard Ubuntu with the Shell installed?

Comment: The credit for PPA's, packages, and easy software installation/uninstallation actually goes to Debian, upon which Ubuntu is based. Ubuntu is really just Debian Linux with some features and a fine layer of polish added.

Answer (score 1):

As said in http://ubuntugnome.org/documentation/faq, Ubuntu GNOME Remix, is just Ubuntu with the GNOME desktop environment.

It's like Kubuntu (Ubuntu with KDE), Xubuntu (Ubuntu with Xfce) and Lubuntu (Ubuntu with LXDE) and is also officially supported.

So the packages that you use on Ubuntu will probably work on Ubuntu GNOME Remix.

The official Ubuntu GNOME Remix official website: http://ubuntugnome.org

Comment: An important distinction here is that UGR is an unofficial derivative, which may be important to some people who want to stick to supported releases.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Thanks for noting that, while you wrote this commentary I was adding this to the answer.

Comment: Ubuntu GNOME is official and I edited it long ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should be just fine installing Gnome Shell on Ubuntu and leaving Unity as-is. I've done that many times and had great success. I currently use Unity because it's grown on me, but it certainly is possible to use them side-by-side.

I haven't tried Gnome Remix, but it doesn't seem necessary to me when Ubuntu works just fine with Gnome Shell.